# C++ class specialiation when dealing with STL containers

Tags: c++, templates, stl, vector, specialization

I'd like a function to return the size in bytes of an object for fundamental types.  I'd also like it to return the total size in bytes of an STL container.  (I know this is not necessarily the size of the object in memory, and that's okay).

To this end, I've coded a `memorysize` namespace with a `bytes` function such that `memorysize::bytes(double x) = 8` (on most compilers).

I've specialized it to correctly handle `std::vector<double>` types, but I don't want to code a different function for each class of the form `std::vector<ANYTHING>`, so how do I change the template to correctly handle this case?

Here's the working code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// return the size of bytes of an object (sort of...)
namespace memorysize
{

  /// general object
  template <class T>
  size_t bytes(const T & object)
  {
    return sizeof(T);
  }

  /// specialization for a vector of doubles
  template <>
  size_t bytes<std::vector<double> >(const std::vector<double> & object)
  {
    return sizeof(std::vector<double>) + object.capacity() * bytes(object[0]);
  }

  /// specialization for a vector of anything???

}


int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{

  // make sure it works for general objects
  double x = 1.;
  std::cout << "double x\n";
  std::cout << "bytes(x) = " << memorysize::bytes(x) << "\n\n";

  int y = 1;
  std::cout << "int y\n";
  std::cout << "bytes(y) = " << memorysize::bytes(y) << "\n\n";

  // make sure it works for vectors of doubles
  std::vector<double> doubleVec(10, 1.);
  std::cout << "std::vector<double> doubleVec(10, 1.)\n";
  std::cout << "bytes(doubleVec) = " << memorysize::bytes(doubleVec) << "\n\n";

  // would like a new definition to make this work as expected
  std::vector<int> intVec(10, 1);
  std::cout << "std::vector<int> intVec(10, 1)\n";
  std::cout << "bytes(intVec) = " << memorysize::bytes(intVec) << "\n\n";

  return 0;
}
```

How do I change the template specification to allow for the more general `std::vector<ANYTHING>` case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modified your code accordingly:

```
/// specialization for a vector of anything
template < typename Anything >
size_t bytes(const std::vector< Anything > & object)
{
  return sizeof(std::vector< Anything >) + object.capacity() * bytes( object[0] );
}
```

Note that now you have a problem if invoking `bytes` with an empty `vector`.

**Edit:** Scratch that. If I remember your previous question correctly, then if you get a vector of strings then you would like to take into account the size taken by each string. So instead you should do

```
/// specialization for a vector of anything
template < typename Anything >
size_t bytes(const std::vector< Anything > & object)
{
  size_t result = sizeof(std::vector< Anything >);

  foreach elem in object
       result += bytes( elem );

  result += ( object.capacity() - object.size() ) * sizeof( Anything ).

  return result;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks!  For now, I'm not dealing with strings so I think I'll skip the foreach step, and just check for the case when capacity = 0.  Hm... 6 minute response time, I should post here more often. :)

Comment: `capacity = 0` wont do what you think. Better check for `vector.empty()`.